# Do I have a wide row?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I created a table with this staement

```
CREATE TABLE history (
  salt int,
  tagName varchar,
  day timestamp,
  room int static,
  component varchar static,
  instance varchar static,
  property varchar static,
  offset int,
  value float,
  PRIMARY KEY ((salt,tagName,day), offset)
);
```

The goal is to have for each rowkey (salt, tagName, day)

- One column for component, instance and property.
- One column for each offset with value as column value.

Day is just the current day (e.g. '2016-06-08'), not the current timestamp.

Salt will be very small. It is there to avoid exceeding row size if data is sampled very fast

I wanted to check my schema with the thrift client but it is no longer installed with the 3.5 version I have.

Is my schema correct for my goal? Is there a way to see the actual 'physical' rows with cqlsh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cassandra-cli equivalent of your cql will be

```
RowKey (salt:tagName:day)
column(offsetvalue:,value= ,timestamp=sometimestamp)
column(offsetvalue:room,value=roomValue,timestamp=sometimestamp)
column(offsetvalue:component ,value=componentValue,timestamp=sometimestamp)
column(offsetvalue:instance,value=instanceValue,timestamp=sometimestamp)
column(offsetvalue:property,value=propertyValue,timestamp=sometimestamp)
column(offsetvalue:value,value=valueValue,timestamp=sometimestamp)
```

Comment: Technically, it will still be a wide row. It's just grouped/rounded by the day. If the records are frequent during the day this could be considered a wide row. I'm more interested in the salt, that could be a greater problem, depending on the carnality.

Comment: day is timestamp value if op is using current timestamp then it will not create wide rows since timestamp are in milliseconds. If op is generating it using current date then yes it might be wide row

Comment: @Undefined_variable yes, day is just the current day (e.g. '2016-06-08'), not the current timestamp.

Comment: @Aleksandar Stojadinovic Yes, salt will be very small. It is there to avoid exceeding row size if data is sampled very fast.

Comment: @PeeWee2201, then I believe you do not need the salt at all. Even if you have millisecond sampling that is roughly 85 million records per day. You can fit that in one row.